# Opening a file with a portable program batch

Tags: batch-file, portable-applications

I use a lot of computers at Uni and about, and as such, I use portable programs to do so. For my own curiosity and ease of use, I want to be able to open a file with a program that is not installed on the computer, from my usb.
-This is what ive compiled thus far.

```
@ECHO OFF
start "%cd:~0,3%PortableApps\MnemosynePortable\MnemosynePortable.exe" "%cd:~0,3%Documents\Dropbox\Folders\UNIVERSITY\University\Mnemosyne\2013-SEM1.db"
```

The problem is, '.db' extension is not registered to work with 'MnemosynePortable.exe'.

Can someone assist?

**edit**
missing quotation marks after `start`, for future reference

Comment: 1) if the path in your batch is correct, you should'nt get this error message, check the path. 2) do you really want to register a program on USB?

Comment: Thanks for the input. The paths are correct, what do you mean by "register a program on USB"?

Comment: I mean: assign a file extension to a "opening program" in the registry. so you can double click on the file to start the "opening program" with that file.

Comment: I get it now, these computers are locked down by admin so I can't access the registry. Even when you assign the extension a program via the W7 OS, it is reset upon logging out. Thanks for answering though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not convinced of your analysis of your problem.

What stands out is that your command line is not balanced - the program-name has no opening quote.

Next issue is that the `start` syntax will interpret such a line as a window-name followed by `"...-sem1.db"` - and that is what it can't associate.

So - Easy solution is to add a pair of rabbits' ears around your desired window-name, and then another to balance the single enclosing the executable name.

```
start "your window name - may be empty" "%cd....
```

OR - since the executable-name does not contain spaces, remove the quote after `.exe`

```
start %cd....table.exe "%cd...sem1.db"
```

Either should cure your problem. Personally, I'd choose the first.

Comment: tested it, you are right. without the double quote you get an error message :)

Comment: Thanks for the positive critism, the posted quesiton didn't have quotes, but I checked the batch and it did and it doesn't work (Same error as in question). Having said that, the solution you posted using - `start "your window name - may be empty" "%cd....' **did** infact work. Many thanks!